# Vim shared copy register

Tags: vim

When working with Vim I often work from multiple monitors and multiple split terminals so I have multiple instances of VIM running at all time. Is there a way to have a persistent shared register that allows me to share the copy paste buffer(Buffer maybe the wrong term here) Is there a setting in VIM or a plugin that would allow me to do this. 
 And example of the work flow I want is to open VIM and yank text close vim Go to another terminal open VIM and paste that yoinked text.

Answer (score 6):

The persistent shared register is the system clipboard. [A similar question has been posted at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144065/how-do-i-copy-and-paste-from-bash-to-vim-and-vice-versa-using-only-the-keyboard/8185654#8185654). This is the answer I posted there:

Use the `*` (or `+` in X Windows) registers to reference the system clipboard. Anything yanked-to or pasted-from those registers can be used to cooperate with other applications:

### Cut/Copy examples

**`"*yy`** : copy current line to the system clipbard

**`gg"*yG`** : copy current file to the system clipbard

**`"*dd`** : cut current line to the system clipbard

etc, etc

---

### Paste examples

**`"*p`** : paste the system clipbard

Or in insert mode:

**`i`** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> **`*`**

Or

**`i`** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> **`*`**

(the last one pastes without formatting, useful to avoid those ugly pastes from the OS clipboard where each indented line appears more and more shifted)